# Computing the wedge product of some differentials

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra

I am trying to compute the wedge product of
\begin{align*}
&2x_p \mathrm{d}x_p \bigwedge_{i=1,\cdots,p-1}2(x_i \mathrm{d}x_i
+y_i\mathrm{d}y_i)\bigwedge_{i=1,\cdots,p-1}x_{i+1}\mathrm{d}y_i+y_i\mathrm{d}x_{i+1},\qquad\qquad
\end{align*}
I tried computing first
\begin{align}
2(x_i \mathrm{d}x_i+y_i\mathrm{d}y_i)&\wedge x_{i+1}\mathrm{d}y_i+y_i\mathrm{d}x_{i+1}
\\&=(2x_ix_{i+1})\mathrm{d}x_i\wedge \mathrm{d}y_i+
(2x_iy_{i})\mathrm{d}x_i\wedge \mathrm{d}x_{i+1}
+(2y_i^2)\mathrm{d}y_i\wedge \mathrm{d}x_{i+1}
\\
&=(2x_ix_{i+1})\mathrm{d}x_i\wedge \mathrm{d}y_i+
(2x_iy_{i})\mathrm{d}x_i\wedge \mathrm{d}x_{i+1}
-(2y_i^2)\mathrm{d}x_{i+1}\wedge \mathrm{d}y_i
\end{align}
But here I don't know what to do.

Comment: What is $m$? I assume $m=p$. The factors of $2$ check, so I would get rid of all the $2$'s. You also desperately need parentheses on the left-hand side of your displayed equation. There is also a sign issue, I think. Have you written it out explicitly for $p=2$ and $p=3$? If you do, you will see many terms disappearing in front of your eyes (because $dx_3\wedge dx_3=0$ and then $dy_2\wedge dy_2=0$ and then $dx_2\wedge dx_2=0$). This should show you how to proceed in general.

Comment: @TedShifrin I tried again computing it for $p=2$. I edited my post. I am not sure if my computation is correct since I am not used to work with the wedge product. Would you take a look at it if this is correct?

Comment: What is the order of the wedge product?

Comment: Anyway. In my calculation it is off by a sign. I don't know why. And your calculation of the wedge product of $(x_1 \mathrm{d}x_1+y_1\mathrm{d}y_1)$ and $x_{2}\mathrm{d}y_1+y_1\mathrm{d}x_{2}$ should have at most 4 terms. I don't see how you have six terms.

Comment: You are listing $2p-1$ many one forms and you want to take "wedge product of them". In which order? Note that $\alpha \wedge \beta \neq \beta \wedge \alpha$ in general.

Comment: I don't understand the "adding the last differential" part — this should go from a $2$-form to a $3$-form. (I'm not worrying about signs at this juncture.) Start with $(x_2\,dy_1+y_1\,dx_2)\wedge (x_2\,dx_2) = x_2^2 dy_1\wedge dx_2$. Now wedge with $x_1\,dx_1+y_1\wedge dy_1$. Note that the $dy_1$ term drops out and we get just $x_1\,dx_1\wedge (x_2^2 dy_1\wedge dx_2) = x_1x_2^2 dx_1\wedge dy_1\wedge dx_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you (or your reference) like to order index in decreasing order, which makes the induction argument a bit weird. I assume $\mathrm{d} \vec x = \mathrm{d} x_p \wedge \mathrm{d} x_{p-1}\wedge \cdots \wedge \mathrm{d} x_1$ and similar for $\mathrm{d}\vec y$.

We prove by induction on $p$.

When $p=2$,

\begin{align}
& (2x_2 \mathrm{d}x_2)\wedge (2(x_1 \mathrm{d}x_1
+y_1\mathrm{d}y_1)) \wedge (x_{2}\mathrm{d}y_1+y_1\mathrm{d}x_{2})\\
&= 2^2 x_2 \mathrm{d}x_2 \wedge (x_1 x_2\mathrm{d}x_1 \wedge\mathrm{d}y_1 + x_1 y_1 \mathrm{d}x_1 + y_1^2 \mathrm{d} y_1\wedge \mathrm{d} x_2) \\
&= 2^2 ( x_1x_2^2 \mathrm{d} x_2 \wedge \mathrm{d}x_1 \wedge\mathrm{d}y_1)  \\
&= 2^2 x_1 x_2^2\mathrm{d} \vec x \wedge\mathrm{d}\vec y. 
\end{align}
So it's true for $p=2$.

Now assume that it's true for $p = p_0$. For $p = p_0+1$,

\begin{align}
A_{p_0+1} &= (2x_{p_0+1} \mathrm{d} x_{p_0+1} ) \wedge \bigwedge_{i=p_0}^1 2(x_i \mathrm{d}x_i
+y_i\mathrm{d}y_i) \wedge \bigwedge _{i=p_0}^1 (x_{i+1}\mathrm{d}y_i+y_i\mathrm{d}x_{i+1}) \\
&= (2x_{p_0+1} \mathrm{d} x_{p_0+1} ) \wedge \bigwedge_{i=p_0}^2 2(x_i \mathrm{d}x_i +y_i\mathrm{d}y_i) \wedge \bigwedge _{i=p_0}^2 (x_{i+1}\mathrm{d}y_i+y_i\mathrm{d}x_{i+1}) \\
& \  \ \  \wedge (-1)^{p_0-1} 2(x_1 \mathrm{d}x_1+y_1\mathrm{d}y_1) \wedge (x_{2}\mathrm{d}y_1+y_1\mathrm{d}x_{2}) 
\end{align}

Now apply the induction hypothesis on
$$ (2x_{p_0+1} \mathrm{d} x_{p_0+1} ) \wedge \bigwedge_{i=p_0}^2 2(x_i \mathrm{d}x_i +y_i\mathrm{d}y_i) \wedge \bigwedge _{i=p_0}^2 (x_{i+1}\mathrm{d}y_i+y_i\mathrm{d}x_{i+1}) $$
to obtain

\begin{align}
A_{p_0+1} &= (2^{p_0}x_2 \prod\limits_{i=3}^{p_0+1} x_i^2)\;\bigwedge_{i=p_0+1}^2 \mathrm{d} x_i\wedge \bigwedge_{i=p_0}^2 \mathrm{d}\vec y\\
& \  \ \  \wedge (-1)^{p_0-1} 2(x_1 \mathrm{d}x_1+y_1\mathrm{d}y_1) \wedge (x_{2}\mathrm{d}y_1+y_1\mathrm{d}x_{2}) \\
&=  (2^{p_0}x_2 \prod\limits_{i=3}^{p_0+1} x_i^2)\;\bigwedge_{i=p_0+1}^2 \mathrm{d} x_i\wedge \bigwedge_{i=p_0}^2 \mathrm{d}\vec y\\
& \  \ \  \wedge (-1)^{p_0-1} 2(x_1x_2 \mathrm{d}x_1\wedge \mathrm{d}y_1 + x_1y_1 \mathrm{d}x_1\wedge \mathrm{d}x_2+y_1^2 \mathrm{d}y_1\wedge \mathrm{d}x_2)\\
&=  (2^{p_0+1}x_1x_2 x_2 \prod\limits_{i=3}^{p_0+1} x_i^2)\;\bigwedge_{i=p_0+1}^2 \mathrm{d} x_i \wedge \mathrm{d}x_1 \wedge \bigwedge_{i=p_0}^2 \mathrm{d}y_i \wedge \mathrm{d}y_1 \\
&= (2^{p_0+1}x_1 \prod\limits_{i=2}^{p_0+1} x_i^2)\;\bigwedge_{i=p_0+1}^1 \mathrm{d} x_i \wedge \bigwedge_{i=p_0}^1 \mathrm{d}y_i. 
\end{align}

Thus it is also true for $p_0+1$. By induction we have proved the assertion.